# save entity into core data with wizard

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

i need to save data in multiple step like a wizard e.g name, family and ... in firstviewcontroller Next adress in secendviewcontroller next image in thirdviewcontroller next ... and in lastviecontroller if user click on finish whole entity save into core data,  so i need something to hold temporary data before last step of wizard. i think i need a Separat class to hold temporary data but i don't know how can i implement that.
I am new in ios and i need a Full description.
 help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for separate class. Just pass your partially populated managed object on to the next controller. You can even do a partial save in between with

```
[context save:nil];
```

(will work across restarts). To cancel, just delete the object with

```
[context deleteObject:object];
```

Comment: but if i want implement with a class how can i do this

Comment: This is too basic. You need to read the documentation before using Core Data and get familiar with NSManagedObject subclasses. First of all, you should accept above answer, as it addresses your problem directly. The managed object subclassing is really a different question.

Comment: i just need an example sir

Comment: You do not need an example because there is nothing for you to do. Just use the model editor to generate the subclasses. (Choose "Editor - Create NSManagedObject Subclass..."). - No more questions answered before you accept the above answer. [See Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdManagedObjects.html)